# Why can’t restore from snapshot in DigitalOcean?

Tags: backup, vps

In my droplet `d1` in DigitalOcean (a VPS server), I take a snapshot named `s1`,and then destroy the droplet `d1`, re-create a droplet `d2`, there is the `s1` in the panel images snapshot.

[image]

When I want to restore from the snapshot I go into the droplet `d2` and select snapshot to restore, the message in the screen:

> Currently you do not have any snapshots for this droplet to restore from.

Can I restore droplet from snapshot `d1`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [to DigitalOcean themselves](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/digitalocean-backups-and-snapshots-explained?comment=179) in the comments on this page:

> You can restore a saved image by creating a new droplet from the
>   chosen snapshot.
>
> When creating a new droplet, clicking on the tab called "My Images" in
>   the "Select a New Droplet Image" section will show you all of the
>   snapshots that you can then spin up a droplet from.